# SignalR - OnDisconnected is called too late

Tags: c#, server, signalr, connection-timeout

I'm having a self hosted SignalR 2.2.0 server and using OWIN for the configuration.

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Server.Communication.StartUp))]
namespace Server.Communication
{
    public class StartUp
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.Map("/Communication", map =>
            {
                map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration { EnableDetailedErrors = true};
                map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Im starting the server via

```
WebApp.Start($"http://{ip}:{port}");
```

And in my `Hub` I've overridden the method

```
public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
```

Everything works fine and the `OnDisconnected` method is called if I let my client crash via windows task explorer to simulate a crash. But the `OnDisconnected` method is called a bit late. There are at least 30 seconds till the method is called. I want to set this time to 10 seconds.

I tried setting `KeepAlive` and `ConnectionTimeout` before i call the `WebApp.Start` method but it did not change anything.

```
GlobalHost.Configuration.ConnectionTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
GlobalHost.Configuration.KeepAlive = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
```

Comment: Reliably detecting broken sockets is one of those *really hard* problems; the only *actual* way to do it is to *reliably* is to occasionally receive data (usually via a server-initiated ping). Broken sockets are often undetectable and don't show up on the still-living end as "dead", so you usually just have to kill them with a timeout if you haven't heard from them inside an expected interval. Obviously, you don't want to be *constantly* sending "I'm still here", "I'm still here", "I'm still here", so some latency in socket closure detection is inherent and unavoidable.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Yes, I don't want to send "I'm still here" messages. Is there no other way to specify the timespan my server is waiting till it calls the `OnDisconnected` method?

Comment: Server is not waiting - it just doesn't know connection is already dead.

Comment: Ok, thank you for this information.

Comment: If the connection is closed ungracefully the server waits for the reconnect and if the client does not reconnect within the DisconnectTimeout the server will consider the connection dead and will call OnDisconnected.

Comment: @Pawel That means I can change the DisconnectTimeout?

Comment: You can change DisconnectTimeout but this has consequences - the interval in which keep alive messages are being sent by default depends on DisconnectTimeout. Also, if you do it incorrectly the server can disconnect active connections. If the client crashes why does it matter how soon OnDisconnected is called?